# Hyperledger fabric - how revocation of root CA certificate works

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

In a scenario where the root CA certificate gets compromised, if I revoke the certificate with serial number and AKI in fabric CA, will it automatically revoke all the certificates created by the root certificate also? Or should I individually revoke each certificate?

Answer (score 1):

MSPs explicitly enumerate the root and intermediate CA certificates, as well as the CRL.  Rather than attempt to add the CA certificate to the CRL, simply remove the CA certificate from the configuration.

In the case of the local MSP, simply delete the PEM file from MSP directory structure and restart the process.

In the case of the channel MSP definitions, simply remove the certificate from the  list of `root_certs` or `intermediate_certs` in [the channel config](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos/blob/9944f8f73cfe0585a477f4b7d56a090374d0c7b6/msp/msp_config.proto#L41-L54).

Once the certificate is no longer in the MSP config, no certs issued by that CA (or its intermediaries) will be considered valid, so there is no need to explicitly list the certs it issued in the CRL.